# Positive and negative powers of small parameter in perturbation problem

Tags: partial-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, perturbation-theory

I'd like to perturbatively handle an eigenvalue problem similar to this:
$$
\lambda f = (\hat{H} + 1/\epsilon^2 \hat{V} + \epsilon {W}) f,
$$
where $f$ is a function, $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue, $\epsilon$ is a small parameter, and the rest are linear (differential) operators. The problem is, that if one writes a series for the eigenvalue and the eigenfunction,
$$
f = f_0 + \epsilon f_1 + \epsilon^2 f_2 + ...\\
\lambda = \lambda_0 + \epsilon \lambda_1 + \epsilon^2 \lambda_2 + ...,
$$
one will get e.g.
$$
\lambda_0 f_0 = \hat{H} f_0 + \hat{V} f_2\\
\lambda_1 f_0 + \lambda_0 f_1 = \hat{H} f_1 + \hat{W} f_0 + \hat{V} f_3\\
...
$$
i.e. the different orders of the series start to mix. Is there a way to develop a systematic perturbation theory for this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the coefficient of the operator $\hat{V}$ is $\epsilon^{-2}$, this provides the dominant contribution for small $\epsilon$. Hence, you should scale your eigenvalue with $\epsilon^{-2}$, i.e. assume an expansion
$$
\lambda = \frac{\lambda_{-2}}{\epsilon^2} + \frac{\lambda_{-1}}{\epsilon} + \lambda_0 + \epsilon \lambda_1 + \ldots.
$$
You can leave the expansion of $f$ as it is, since both sides of your equation scale with $f$.

Comment: This is a nice answer. Is there any source or brief reference that you recommend that discusses this concept of how to appropriately scale in perturbative problems?

Comment: Thanks! The appropriate scaling of perturbation problems is largely a matter of trial and error; in practice, you substitute $\lambda = \epsilon^{\alpha} \lambda_0$ and try to find the value of $\alpha$ for which the leading order equation you obtain is non-trivial. At least, that is the `classical' approach of asymptotic expansions. There are more modern methods that allow you to systematically deduce the asymptotic scaling of system components: I would suggest geometric singular perturbation theory, and its extension, geometric blow-up of singularities.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. By the way, do you have any advice on how to handle this (possibly related) question?: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3987059/perturbation-calculation-of-expression-with-small-parameter-also-appearing-in-ex